# If someone catches an overhead railway power line while standing on top of a train, why wouldn't others in the train be electrocuted also?

Tags: high-voltage, electricity

I recently came upon a video where a man catches a 25kV power line on top of a train.

**BEWARE!!! Video is not safe for the weak hearted.** 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Vt9OLL2bkQ

Why didn't others on the train get electrocuted too? I understand that due to effect of Faraday cage everyone completely inside the train would be unharmed.
But in the video there are several people at the doors holding the door handle with their feet on the platform. Shouldn't they get the shock too?

Comment: To get electrocuted, current has to flow through you.

Comment: Isn't the train's frame made from conductive metal ?

Comment: There was a path to the rails thru the wheels, or to the 3rd rail.

Comment: Why don't people get electrocuted when the overhead wire powers the traction motors via the pantograph and it takes plenty more amps than that poor fool.

Answer (score 5):

You only get an electric shock if the current flows through you.  Anyone inside the train won't be affected simply because they are inside a metal box.  The current flows round the outside and doesn't bother them.

Anyone hanging on the outside of the train, or leaning out of a door, is unlikely to be affected either because the metal body of the train is a much better conductor than a person.  Most of the current would flow through the train body, not the person.

Somebody on the platform may get a shock.  But the metal train wheels on the metal rails make a far better ground connection than a person on a platform.  So the shock would be a lot less than might be expected.